# regex: match between brackets, but result can't be longer than 25 characters

Tags: regex

I have this string

```
(non-standardized SKUs on 1p to 3p to re drag so going forward the focus will continue to be on the apparel category which drives our growth and profitability in a long run). (Foreign Language) So we are actively planning for our June promotional event, which is a
```

I'm using `(?=\()(.*)(?<=\))` to find everything in between the brackets so to remove it using `re.sub(string, '')`. But I don't want to remove anything that is longer than say 25 characters.

Been trying to use something like `{0,25}` in the regex, but I can't get it work.

Comment: Your lookarounds were backwards. [`(?<=\()[^()]{0,25}(?=\))`](https://regex101.com/r/AfNVyU/1) would be what you were looking for. And the capturing group is redundant since you are using positive lookbehind/aheads.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use something like `\([^)]{0,25}\)`.

https://regex101.com/r/9fnuOO/1